# Stripping certain HTML tags from NSString

Tags: html, ios, regex, nsstring, whitelist

Im trying to strip certain HTML tags from an NSString instance, but porting a regexp from javascript results in stripping ALL tags from the string.

I also tested the regexp with Reggy, which indicates its working as intended, but I cant get it to work in iOS.

What am I missing?

```
// remove all tags except the whitelisted ones (b,i,p,a,strong,br,ul,ol,li)
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<(?!/?(?:[bipa]|strong|br|ul|ol|li)\b)[^>]*>" options:0 error:&error];
result = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:someString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

Comment: Have you tried a [non-greedy match](http://robertpyke.blogspot.com/2009/02/ruby-regex-non-greedy-operator-using_05.html)?